# Connect to database from another domain

Tags: dns, host

I have a domain (.com) and a database included with this domain

I also have another domain (.eu) hosted by another hostingcompany but I want to use the database of the .com domain
Is it safe to link to the database with the ipaddress of the .com domain

Or how could I connect to the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Speak to the hosting company - most will firewall their database servers to mitigate hacking. they may be willing to add an exception to give access to your other server.